# PayPal - Unable to verify the payment using Transaction ID (GetTransactionDetails API)

Tags: php, android, paypal, transactions

There are a lot of discussions about similar issues but I couldn’t find the exact answer.

Here is the problem:

I’m trying to integrate in-app payment in Android OS using the latest PayPal MSDK library. The integration was straight forward, I could make successful single payment, receive proper response and the things was OK until I have to [verify the mobile payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/)

In the mobile app(using PayPalConfiguration.ENVIRONMENT_SANDBOX), I receive the following response:

```
{
    "client": {
        "environment": "sandbox",
        "paypal_sdk_version": "2.2.2",
        "platform": "Android",
        "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK"
    },
    "response": {
        "create_time": "2014-08-05T19:49:19Z",
        "id": "PAY-0D205735ER3716140KPQTKPY",
        "intent": "sale",
        "state": "approved"
    },
    "response_type": "payment"
}
```

As you can see, the transaction ID is: **PAY-0D205735ER3716140KPQTKPY**

When I try to verify the payment by making request with this transaction ID from my server to PayPal, the response is always the same:

```
{
"Errors":
     [
        {
        "L_ERRORCODE":"10004",
        "L_SHORTMESSAGE":"Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.",
        "L_LONGMESSAGE":"The transaction id is not valid",
        "L_SEVERITYCODE":"Error"
        }
     ]
}
```

When I check in [PayPal Sandbox test account site -> Notifications](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts), the test transactions ids are completely different. For the above transaction, the transaction id is:
**5DY75733624918945**

If I use this transaction ID in my verification request – the response from the PayPal is OK.

According the documentation, I should use the id from the mobile app response (moreover – I do not know other way to retrieve a transaction id…).

I'm using a test sandbox account, tried with different type of payment (PayPal button and CC), tried even with real transactions - the result is the same.

Do you guys know why they are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a closer look at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

The SDK returns a payment ID which can be used to retrieve a payment resource using GET.  The payment will contain one or more transactions (in your case, a single sale transaction) in the `related_resources` section.

Comment: Thank you Matt. You helped me a lot! I was doing it in a wrong way.

Comment: Glad it helped.  Click the up arrow so others will know more easily that this answer was helpful.

Comment: I've tried but unfortunately, I do not have high enough reputation: "Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @MattJacunski we are  doing andriod app for our magento site. in magento site we integrated paypal successfully.

in app we need some help. our andriod team is telling in app, customer/Buyer enter paypal email id & password ,

than they will pass the transaction id to server[magento] & in server we need to validate it. how to achieve this ?